# How to Remove This Fork?

Tags: fork, stem

I'm restoring another old bike of mine (20 y.o).
Want to repaint the bike, but I need to remove all the parts.
Trying to remove the old rusty fork but have no idea how to do it.
I tried to remove the hex nut with wrench, but it didn't even move at all.
Trying to hit it with rubber mallet, but still not moving at all.

[image: the forkin fork]
[image: fork]
[image]
Any idea?

Comment: I feel for you.  I've got a bike in much better condition where I can't adjust the stem because the stem bolt is frozen.  Planning to turn it over and flood the tube with oxalic acid when I get the chance (and the weather permits).

Answer (score 7):

You first **have** to remove the quill stem. To remove you undo the bolt from the top (blue arrow), and then you will probably need to tap it lightly with a hammer to push the bung nut out the bottom so it's loose enough to remove.

Once you remove the stem, you need to remove the headset lock nut (red arrow). Once this is removed, you can remove the headset nut/race (yellow arrow).

Watch out for the bearings inside the headset, they may be in a cage, they may be loose, or they may be in a worn out cage that doesn't hold them properly any more.

[image]

Here is a general quill stem diagram for you to understand what locks it in place
[image]

And here is a general threaded headset diagram.
[image]

Comment: Already removed  the upper bolt, it's already loose and I can remove the upper bolt. For the headset lock nut, it didnt even bulge
Is it the right step? I watched some video and they just remove the upper bolt and then hammer the fork from bottom

Comment: Put the upper bolt (part C in the diagram) back in, but only screw it in part way. Then whack it straight down with a hammer. That should loosen up the nut (part D in the diagram) so that the whole stem can come out. Then unscrew the lock nut (counter clockwise when looking down from the top). Rust can make all of this much, much harder.

Comment: Nope, tried it and it didnt bulge, also sprayed some rust buster penetrating oil and hit it with mallet, still it didnt move at all
The rust really make it much much much much harder

Comment: @codearm2 That 7-shaped thing should entirely come out, including that triangle shaped wedge at the bottom of the assembly.

Comment: If I am interpreting these photos correctly, in photo 3 it looks as if you partly extracted the stem and cut off the forward extension. If that's correct, you should still be able to loosen the locknut, but you'll need to fix the forks in place. Your setup is different from the diagram that @abdnChap posted: you don't have both a locknut and adjustable cup, you have only a locknut. If you've cut off the stem extension, you'll need to punch out the stem wedge after you get the fork clear.

Comment: With the bolt back in and backed off by just one turn, use a solid hammer rather than a rubber mallet to generate a shock. How desperate are you to get it off and how prepared are you with write off the fork - might be time to let the inner Gorilla out.

Comment: Start with a light tap not a solid breaking whack.  Then gradually upsize the hit until it moves.  If it breaks, then you needed a new one anyway!   There is no need to cut anything here.

Comment: @Adam Rice It looks like they just spun the bars 180° around. No cutting involved. You can see in photo #1 that this stem isn’t the most refined looking thing anyways.

Comment: I could tell that the next problem of the same type will arise with the seatpost. But that question has been answered and there are a number of YT & Parktool videos on the subject. For this one here as well!